# Express, async initialization with callback

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express. I am adding routes dynamically (routes config is stored in mongodb)

```
const app = require('express')();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var proxyHandler = { 

    paths: [ '/demoservice' ],
    proxy: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://test/demo',
    name: 'demoservice',
    _id: ""
}

app.use(proxyHandler.paths,function(req,res){

        // do stuff
});
```

**What if I want to make a mongodb call and pull routes config and then do app.use**

here is my function to get list of routes, but this is async, if I loop over result and try to do `app.use()` for each route it doesn't work

```
function getAllActiveRoutes(cb){

    routes.find({active:true},function(err,result){
        if(err){
            return cb(err)
        } else {
            return cb(null,result)
            ** this is not working
            result.forEach(function(r){
             app.use(r.paths,function(req,res){
                   res.render(something)
            })})
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
routes.find({active:true},function(err,result){
    if(err){
        return cb(err)
    } else {
        return cb(null, function() {
            result.forEach(function(r){
               app.use(r.paths,function(req,res){
                  res.render(something);
               });
            });
       });
    }
})
```